# Vertically Centered Table Header and General Table Aesthetics

Tags: tables, header-footer, vertical-alignment

What what be the best way of making "ID" vertically centered in the header in the table below?

Also, are there any suggestions or recommendations that anyone would have to make this table more aesthetically pleasing? Thanks!

[image: table1]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[abbreviations=true,per-mode=symbol]{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Specific Acid Added to Samples}
\label{Acid_Added}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ >{\bfseries}c  S[table-format=2.2]  S[table-format=2.2]  S[table-format=1.2] }
\toprule
ID & {Specific Acid} & {Spread} & {Specific Acid} \\
& {Weight [\si{\mg}]} & {Weight [\si{\g}]} & {Conc [\si{\mg\per\g}]} \\
\midrule
1   &0.20   &19.96  &0.01\\
2   &0.40   &20.00  &0.02\\
3   &1.00   &19.98  &0.05\\
4   &2.00   &20.00  &0.10\\
5   &4.00   &20.00  &0.20\\
6   &10.00  &20.00  &0.50\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two versions of your table in which I vertically centered  `ID` using the `\thead` command from the `makecell` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[abbreviations=true,per-mode=symbol]{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Specific Acid Added to Samples}
\label{Acid_Added}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ >{\bfseries}c  S[table-format=2.2]  S[table-format=2.2]  S[table-format=1.2] }
\toprule
\thead{ID} & {\thead{Specific Acid\\ Weight [\si{\mg}]}} & {\thead{Spread\\ Weight [\si{\g}]}} & {\thead{Specific Acid\\Conc [\si{\mg\per\g}]}} \\
\midrule
1   &0.20   &19.96  &0.01\\
2   &0.40   &20.00  &0.02\\
3   &1.00   &19.98  &0.05\\
4   &2.00   &20.00  &0.10\\
5   &4.00   &20.00  &0.20\\
6   &10.00  &20.00  &0.50\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{table}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize}
\caption{Specific Acid Added to Samples}
\label{Acid_Added}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ >{\bfseries}c  S[table-format=2.2]  S[table-format=2.2]  S[table-format=1.2] }
\toprule
\thead{ID} & {\thead{Specific Acid\\ Weight [\si{\mg}]}} & {\thead{Spread\\ Weight [\si{\g}]}} & {\thead{Specific Acid\\Conc [\si{\mg\per\g}]}} \\
\midrule
1   &0.20   &19.96  &0.01\\
2   &0.40   &20.00  &0.02\\
3   &1.00   &19.98  &0.05\\
4   &2.00   &20.00  &0.10\\
5   &4.00   &20.00  &0.20\\
6   &10.00  &20.00  &0.50\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Personaly, I'd prefer a table without using bold for the ID's and I'd also use the `caption` package to control the spacing etween caption and toprule:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[abbreviations=true,per-mode=symbol]{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Specific Acid Added to Samples}
\label{Acid_Added}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c  S[table-format=2.2]  S[table-format=2.2]  S[table-format=1.2] }
\toprule
\thead{ID} & {\thead{Specific Acid\\ Weight [\si{\mg}]}} & {\thead{Spread\\ Weight [\si{\g}]}} & {\thead{Specific Acid\\Conc [\si{\mg\per\g}]}} \\
\midrule
1   &0.20   &19.96  &0.01\\
2   &0.40   &20.00  &0.02\\
3   &1.00   &19.98  &0.05\\
4   &2.00   &20.00  &0.10\\
5   &4.00   &20.00  &0.20\\
6   &10.00  &20.00  &0.50\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @leandriis, if I want to move the units to the next line in the header (e.g. [mg/g] on a new line), how would I be able to do that? Right now if I do that with \\ I get an error for the [] brackets, but not if I use () brackets

Comment: `\\{}` as in `\thead{Specific Acid\\ Weight\\{} [\si{\mg}]}` should work for that.

Answer (score 0):

The `multirow` package allows you to vertically fuse cells together. Once it has been loaded in your preamble, you can use the command `\multirow{<number of cells to fuse>}{<width>}{<content>}`.
Note that you can replace the `width` with a `*` to respect the given cell width.

Comment: Also, this question probably has already been asked and answered somewhere on TeXSE.